# change row font color in dojo dataGrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

How can I change the color of my text in a specific row of my dataGrid?

I can use this code for changing the bg-color but why is the color not changing?

```
dojo.connect(mygrid, 'onStyleRow', this, function (row) {
    var item = mygrid.getItem(row.index);
    if (row.index === 14) {
        row.customClasses = "highlightRow";
        row.customStyles += 'background-color:#E20074;';
        row.customStyles += 'color:#ffffff;';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onStyleRow function: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#grid-styling-rows
Function should be connected before DataGrid started - in declaration.